# Unable to print Arabic string by bluetooth thermal printer from my android app

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, arabic, arabic-support

I want to print a string by my thermal Bluetooth printer using my android app.
I made the connection and it already prints English strings very well. However, when I try to print an Arabic string, it prints our garbage.

This is my code for printing

```
  void sendData() throws IOException {
        try {

            String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
            msg += "\n";
            mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I got "ISO-8859-1" as the charset name for Arabic language from the following link

http://jkorpela.fi/chars/sorted.html

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello.. Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Try converting text to bitmap and print bitmap.

Comment: Any answer ????

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the character table for your printer and write the corresponding commands to let the printer know that you are printing multi byte characters such as Arabic characters.
In my case, I was using sunmi printer and the only thing that worked for me was finding its character table and I wrote the commands and it worked very well.
Here's a picture of what they said in the documentation.
[a picture of what they said in the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raSXY.png)

And this is what I did and it worked perfectly

```
 const utf8Encoder = Utf8Encoder();
    final encodedStr = utf8Encoder.convert(invoice.description);
    bytes += generator.textEncoded(Uint8List.fromList([
      ...[0x1C, 0x26, 0x1C, 0x43, 0xFF],
      ...encodedStr
    ]));
```